# Run code ONCE on startup

Tags: android

I want to run a small piece of code each time the app starts up. I have tried the following:

- In the Activity.onCreate(). But this won't work as the activity could get re-created on rotation for example.
- Create a subclass of Application and run in onCreate() there. This doesn't seem to work either. It gets executed when the app is installed, but not when you back-out of the application and go into it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Amorogos: use refresh handler to refresh that piece of code with appropriate time dealy

Comment: But I only want to run it once when the user Launches the app.

Comment: What is it supposed to do ? is it a temporal issue ? then you could compare the time of the last execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main activity, declare a static boolean flag that you set to `true` when you run the start-up code. In `onCreate`, run the start-up code only if the flag is `false`. In `onDestroy` (or in any of the shut-down lifecycle methods, for that matter), clear the flag if the activity is finishing:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        startedFlag = false;
    }
}
```

This will clear the flag when the activity is finishing but leave it untouched if the activity is being destroyed because of a configuration change.

There's still a catch: the activity's process might be killed off while paused and the app is in the background. In that case, the flag will be `false` when the activity is recreated by the system when the user tries to bring the app back to the foreground. If this is a problem, then you are going to have to make the flag persistent. I'd recommend using shared preferences for that.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do this but was missing the static declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [How can I execute something just once per application start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360846/how-can-i-execute-something-just-once-per-application-start)

> - Create a subclass of Application and run in onCreate() there. This
>     doesn't seem to work either. It gets executed when the app is
>     installed, but not when you back-out of the application and go into
>     it again

You need to put your code in the constructor and not in the onCreate() method. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13809300/2005891

Comment: Please, full code?