# Welcome page for Android App

Tags: android

I am new to android development, and developing a small app for practice purposes.
I want the following:
When the user installs the app, he/she is greeted with a set of welcome pages, that give details about the app, and then proceeds to the actual app.
But I don't want that set of pages to appear anytime after the first time the app is opened.
So how do I go about implementing that?

PS: This is my first question posted, excuse typos or brevity if any.

Edit: It seems like there is another question of the same context, but I also want to know how to make such an activity that will load only once after the installation.

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far? What are your current ideas?

Comment: start android from this site - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html,   https://developer.android.com/training/index.html,   and some like http://www.androidhive.info/, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute something just once per application start?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360846/how-can-i-execute-something-just-once-per-application-start)

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes but it answers only a part of question, I also want to learn to make an activity that will appear only once after installing.

Comment: You just call `startActivity` when your boolean flag is true, otherwise dont

Comment: @howdoidothis I think I will have to use intents, but was not sure about the SharedPreferences

Comment: @REHANSHIKKALGAR I will refer, thank you so much.

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay will surely try, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result in different way, one of them may be to 
store on SharedPreference

```
isFirstLoad = true
```

after the user read you intro page then

```
isFirstLoad = false
```

in your main activity check for first load to redirect user to correct activity

```
Intent i = ...// normal activity
if(isFirstLoad){
    i = ...// intro activity
}
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use SharedPrefrences for store that it is the first time or not.
you can creat a class for store information like this.

```
public class prefrence
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public prefrence(Context context)
    {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppData", 0);
    }

    public boolean isFirstTime()
    {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", true);
    }

    public void setFirstTime(boolean b)
    {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("first", b).commit();
    }

}
```

and check that it is first time or not like this:

```
if (new preference(context).isFirstTime()) {
    showSplash();
    new preference(context).setFirstTime(false);
}
```