# Application.onCreate called more than once

Tags: android

I have an application where I extend Application class and override the onCreate method.

In my onCreate, I schedule a service to run every 5 minutes using AlarmManager.

In the logs, I see that onCreate get's called again after a while as though the application was restarted / recreated. 

this ends up with my service not being synchronized with the first execution.

Is there a way to prevent this and to guaranty code in Application's onCreate will execute exactly once (assuming of course the application wasn't explicitly closed by the user)?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Is this happening if you change the orientation of the device?

Comment: I guess orientation changes several times, but this is when application is in background and also, this should affect activities, not application. in the logs I see it a few times on a period of more than 20 minutes so I guess it's not related to configuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreate()` on your `Application` is called as part of starting up your process. If you are seeing it called several times in the logs, that is because your process was terminated in between runs.

Comment: So is the AlarmManager restarting it? How can I prevent / detect such cases in order to maintain correct service execution in defined interval?

Comment: @Oren: "So is the AlarmManager restarting it?" -- since I do not have access to your logs, I have no way of answering that. You should be able to tell that based on log timestamps. "How can I prevent / detect such cases in order to maintain correct service execution in defined interval?" -- don't start up a service from `onCreate()` of `Application`. Or, keep track of when your service runs (e.g., `lastRunTime` value in `SharedPreferences`) and only kick off `AlarmManager` if you determine that your service has not been running.

Comment: from the logs I see that the process is recreated (different pid) when I enter the main activity after some time - meaning the process is recreated in some cases to open the activity. I don't want to use SharedPreferences because this will mean I will have to maintain many use cases (e.g. boot, closing from task manager etc)

Comment: @Oren: You cannot stop `onCreate()` from being called. You cannot stop your process from being terminated.

Comment: That I understand. what I'm asking is if there is a way that calls to AlarmManager to schedule a service will not be called multiple times because of android's processes management...

Comment: @Oren: If you use an equivalent `PendingIntent` each time, each call to `setRepeating()` should replace the old one. Or, you can manually `cancel()` the old one, if it exists.

Comment: Yes, what I needed was that the service will be executed by AlarmManager at fixed interval, and I can't achieve it this way as Process gets teminated and recreated and calls to AlarmManager are re-executed

Comment: @Oren: You need to keep track of when your service runs, anyway, as there are various scenarios when your alarms get unscheduled (reboot, force stop). so, as I suggested, keep a `lastRunTime` somewhere, and if it has been significantly over your polling period since the last time your service run, reschedule the alarms.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not entirely true. Using different processes, as well as some crash-reporting frameworks can result in `Application.onCreate()` being called multiple times. See [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809737/android-application-class-method-oncreate-being-called-multiple-times) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3951911/383414).