# static variable reinitialization on M but not on L due to Application onCreate() called more than once

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an application which has a class derived from the Application class and have noticed that its onCreate() method is being called multiple times. In addition to this the value of its static variables is being reset each time onCreate() is called.

This behavior only occurs on M, it does not occur on L. I am trying to find out if its a bug in M or an intended change in M or there is some fundamental inherent problem with the app architecture which has lain dormant and only now manifested with M.

The Application derived class's onCreate() is being called whenever a broadcast receiver's onReceive() is called. 
Multiple instances of the Application class are NOT being created - onCreate() is being called on the same object instance, and the same application context is present throughout.

Here's some code snippets demonstrating this observation:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    public static int debugVal = 5;

    public MyApplication ()
    {
        theApp = this;
    }

    public void onCreate ()
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "++++++++++++ onCreate() debugVal: " + debugVal);
        debugVal = 10;
        ....



public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    Log.v(TAG, "onReceive. debugVal: " + MyApplication.debugVal);
    ...
```

When run on Marshmallow the logcat output is:

```
831-1412/? I/ActivityManager Start proc 2244:com.company.redacted/u0a86 for broadcast com.company.redacted/com.company.redacted2.MyBroadcastReceiver
2244-2244/? V/MyApplication: ++++++++++ onCreate() debugVal: 5
2244-2244/? V/MyBroadcastReceiver: onReceive. debugVal: 10
...
831-1327/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 3271.com.company.redacted/u0a86 for broadcast com.company.redacted2/com.company.redacted1.MyBroadcastReceiver
3271-3271/? V/MyApplication: +++++++++++ onCreate() debugVal: 5
....
```

See how onCreate() is called more than once, and how debugVal has lost its value of 10 by the second time onCreate() has been called.
When the same .apk runs on Lollipop the second call to onCreate() is not present.

The log on L looks like this:

```
768-783/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2480:com.company.redacted/u0a84 for broadcast com/company.redacted1/com.company.redacted2/MyBroadcastReceiver
2480-2480/? V/MyApplication: +++++++++++ onCreate() debugVal:5
2480-2480/? V/MyBroadcastReceiver: onReceive. debugVal: 10
....
2480-2480/com.company.redaced1 v/MyBroadcastReceiver: onReceive. debugVal: 10
```

I'd like to know what's going on and eliminate it, but if I can't is it going to be possible to replace the Application class with some singleton class whose static variables are guaranteed to be safe and reliable and initialized only once?

This is a pre-installed app which starts on boot (which is one of the intents the receiver listens to) and doesn't have any Actives at this point.

Comment: What did you comment out? Were the broadcast receiver logs shown from different processes on L?

Comment: I'll add the logs from L in a second. Its a large complex app, it'd take a while to codify everything that was commented out and probably be too much and too confusing to summarize.

Comment: The super.onCreate() is there, its just not in the abbreviated code snippet I posted.

Comment: "Meanwhile you can check if your context is already created if not create it else do nothing" how is that done?

Comment: I think adding that extra code is making your application too memory heavy, promoting the OS to kill it ASAP. onTerminate is not reliable (according to android docs), so try to override and log onTrimMemory() and onLowMemory(). Regardless, the logs (and the process numbers) show that the application is restarting (not sure how you determined that the constructor is called once)

Comment: Sorry my bad. Confused with regular Activity.

Comment: Maybe you have a service that start it in the second time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947052/android-application-class-being-called-twice

Comment: @curly "I think adding that extra code is making your application too memory heavy". But it also occurs in the reduced version if the receiver calls public static variables of the application.  I was mistaken about the constructor. The memory functions aren't being called.

Comment: @Maor Hadid, I don't think so but will investigate (I wasn't the original author). But if that is the case, then wouldn't it also occur on Lollipop? This is only happening on M.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but without any success, I have the same behaviour on Lollipop and Marshmallow. Have you tried with the official release of Android M? Is there any particular reason to test with a preview build?

Comment: It also happens on the MRA58K build. Its a moderately complex app (I didn't write it, its very old) and it seems that its not reproducible by having just the Application class and a receiver in the picture and that other elements in its architecture are resulting in this behavior. However without drawing the full architecture I don't suppose I can get much help on here, unless there are known circumstances which could result in this which I can look for in the code.

Comment: The different PIDs show that Android is definitely starting two separate processes twice. Either the first run is crashing (check logcat) or you have a service configured to run in an isolated process (check manifest for use of android:isolatedProcess).

Comment: Looking through the 6.0 source code I can see that that line of logcat output comes, indirectly, from line 19088 of ActivityManagerService.java, where it has decided to kill an empty process to free up some memory. An "empty" process is one whose static data is initialised but which contains no running application components (activities, services, etc). I hazard a guess that your 6.0 platform is simply rather more memory constrained than your 5.x platform, and you are just seeing the effects of the OS being more aggressive about reclaiming RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say onCreate() is being called twice in the same process but that's probably incorrect. It's very possible that Marshmallow is more aggressive about killing your process, either because less memory available or just being more aggressive about killing idle packages (see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64127) for mention of 'empty #17' and the [docs mentioning CACHED_EMPTY](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/low-ram.html)).

To verify, make your service a foreground service by calling [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) with a persistent notification. If your problems disappear it means the OS was killing your process.

In general you shouldn't rely on staying running in the background - make initializations as lazy and fine-grained as possible, and make background operations like broadcast receivers as cheap as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in log messages you've shown, the whole process is restarted, and hence onCreate is called again, can you describe what happens between the two events, or some details on what you application is doing and what can trigger the killing of the first process and starting a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are bad for holding state. The reason for this that static variables don't survive across lifecycle and app starts/shutdowns. You generally only use static variables for constant state. Which means variables that have the same initial value or are constants.

If the value is changing then it should be stored in storage such as Prefs.

---

As for why you are getting multiple calls to OnCreate; could you elaborate what kind of BroadcastReceiver you are implementing?

It is possible that an incoming intent could be causing a configuration change which would destroy and recreate the Application.