# How to call a method only when the app has been launched? Please see details

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onbackpressed

I have a method in which I'm fetching user's details and some data from `firebase` database.

The problem is that the method is getting called twice or thrice after launching the app and again when I'm navigating back from any other activity.

I have put that method in `onCreate` method like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        checkAuthState();
    }
```

I am sure I haven't called `checkAuthState()` in `onStart()` or `onResume()` methods.

This is how I'm navigating back from other activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Please let me know why `checkAuthState()` is getting called thrice and why it is getting called again when navigating back from any other activity and how to call this method only once when the app has been launched?

Sorry if question seems to be badly formatted. I'm still a beginner!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588682/is-it-normal-for-the-activity-oncreate-method-to-be-called-multiple-times the solution is to use the onSaveInstanceState to keep track of auth state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create launcher activity to checkAuthStatus.
Start a new activity and kill the launcher activity.

Comment: seems like an excellent solution. will try soon. Also pls tell about how to stop onCreate from getting called again when navigating back from other activites?

Answer (score 2):

change your onCreate() method to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        checkAuthState();
    }

}
```

Comment: this called `checkAuthState();` six times!

Comment: This definitely shouldn't make your code run any more than before. Was this the only thing you changed?

Comment: hmmm i just checked this and working fine for me.. i hope you are not calling this function from anywhere else..

Answer (score 0):

You can extends Application and add your own function in `onCreate` just like an Activity. To create your own Application class, change the name of the application in the manifest like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
</application>
```

Then, you can declare MyApplication like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        checkAuthState();
    }
}
```

Of course, `checkAuthState` must be in MyApplication then. An alternate solution which I suggest is to verify changes of authentication with `Firebase.AuthChangeListener`:

```
// Listener to the user's authentication token expiration
Firebase.AuthStateListener authListener = new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
        checkAuthState();
    }
};
mFirebaseReference.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
```