# Why does navigation composable call twice?

Tags: android-jetpack-navigation

Why does navigation composable call twice? If I set a breakpoint on the Text I will get two stops when the app runs. Thank you for your answers.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            var i: Int = 0
            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "s1") {
                composable("s1") {
                    i++
                    Text("$i")

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems related to this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22224038/2191796 . Even after moving `super` call after setContent I still get the double onCreate call. The other suggestion in that thread was creating a new thread/runnable while still inside onCreate. So it seems something about Compose Navigation is creating a new thread or runnable.

Comment: Did you get any answer for this? I am also facing this?

Comment: Have you tried to use 
 navController.navigate with navOptions? for example:
navOptions = navOptions {
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }

Answer (score 0):

`NavHost` is a ***composable***, So naturally it can be composed and recomposed several times! If you want to do a one-time action in a composable lifecycle, use `LaunchedEffect`.

```
fun LaunchedEffect(
    vararg keys: Any?,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
)
```

`LaunchedEffect` is a composable function, so it can only be used inside other composable functions. It is used to trigger **[side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)** that should only be executed once when the key changes.

Change your code as bellow :

```
     setContent {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        var i: Int = 0
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "s1") {
            composable("s1") {
                LaunchedEffect(Unit){
                    i++
                }
                Text("$i")
            }
        }
```

I used *Unit* as LaunchedEffect`s parameter. Since the LaunchedEffect block is relaunched every time its parameter changes, its block will run just one time.

Read this **[article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle)** for a better understanding of the lifecycle of composables